# error c2065 and many other error

Tags: c

I don't know what is wrong in my code. I doing a OS time scheduling program, I only just starting to code and when I try it to just check if its run correct I got an error.

this is my function:

```
void npefcfs()
{
    int process;
    int bt[10];
    printf("    How many process do you like to use: ");
    scanf("%d",&process);
    printf("\n  -----------------------------------------");
    printf("\n  Please Enter Burst time: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < process; i++)
    {
        int num = 1;
        printf("\nP%d =",num);
        num = num + 1;
        scanf("%d", &bt[i]);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < process; k++)
    {
        printf("%d", &bt[k]);
    }
}
```

I keep having an error like

```
error C2065: 'k' : undeclared identifier    
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

I check it many time. I think I correctly declared K and there's shouldn't be missing ';'

Comment: Are you compiling in C99 (or later) mode? Is that really the only relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < process; i++)
```

This syntax only works since C99, but according to your error code, you are using Visual Studio, which doesn't support C99 yet.

You need to declare the variables `i` `k` in the begging of the block, in the C89 style:

```
void npefcfs()
{    
    int process;
    int i, k;
    //...
```

And later use it like:

```
    for (i = 0; i < process; i++)
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, just add `-std=c99` to the compilation flags (assuming GCC).

Comment: @Cornstalks I think error code like `error C2065` implies that it's Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

C99 feature allows the programmer to declare a variable for use by the loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < process; k++);
```

The variable `k` need not have been declared prior to this statement (In fact, if a declaration of `k` already exists, this statement creates a *new* version of `k` that will be used solely within the loop.)
But you can't use this feature in C89 mode. For this you should have to declare variables in the beginning

```
void npefcfs()
{

    int process;
    int bt[10];
    int i, k;
    ....

    for ( i = 0; i < process; i++)
    ....
}
```